# Effect of adding more sample data on Maximum Likelihood estimator

Tags: maximum-likelihood, consistency

I have samples $\{x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots , x_n\}$ of a random variable $X$. I compute Maximum Likelihood Estimator $\hat{\theta}_n$ using the sample data.

Now, if I collect one more sample $x_{n+1}$ and compute the MLE $\hat{\theta}_{n+1}$ again with $n+1$ samples. Would it be possible to prove that $\hat{\theta}_{n+1}$ is a better estimate of true parameter than $\hat{\theta}_{n}$?

Please note that I am only adding one more sample $(x_{n+1})$ to the existing sample set $\{x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n\}$. I am not sampling n+1 data points again.

Comment: No, not for all possible realisations of the $n+1$ sample.

Comment: @Xi'an Can you please elaborate on that? I am not sampling (n+1) data points again. I am only sampling one more data point and adding to the set. Are there any conditions on the (n+1)th sample to make sure that the MLE gets improved.

Comment: With 'better estimate' you mean lower expected mean squared error?

Comment: Do you mean whether $\hat\theta_{n+1}$ is better than $\hat\theta_{n}$, *unconditional* on $\hat\theta_{n}$? When $\hat\theta_{n}$ happens to be close to, or equal to $\theta$, then  $\hat\theta_{n+1}$ won't necessarily be better. So it is not true for every specific case/realization.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings With better estimate I mean if there are any theoretical guarantees that the estimate $\theta_{n+1}$ would be closer to the true parameter when compared with $\theta_n}. I am not looking for the limiting case when n tends to be infinite.

Comment: @Xi'an Yes I am aware of the term.

Comment: @neo89 there are both probabilities of getting closer and further. How do you wish to compare/weigh these? You need to specify it more precisely to get rid of ambiguities.

Comment: For instance, if the $n$-sample is an iid sample from $\mathcal U(0,\theta)$, the best unbiased estimator is $(n+1)x_{(n)}/n$. Observing a new observation $x_{n+1}$ such that $x_{n+1}<x_{(n)}$ leasd to a _worse_ estimator since $(n+2)x_{(n)}/(n+1)<(n+1)x_{(n)}/n$.

Comment: While Xi'ans example is for an unbiased estimator, the same works for the MLE. There will always be a non-zero number of possible results for $x_{n+1}$ that will lead to a worse estimator, or at least not better (the uniform distribution $\mathcal{U}(0,\theta)$ is actually an, not so common, interesting case where an extra sample point can't make the MLE worse). An example is the sample mean for a sample from a normal distributed population, which can get further away from the population mean when you increase the sample size.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Thank you for the clarification. That makes sense. I was looking for a metric analogous to consistency of an MLE but for finite data.

Comment: @neo89, I believe that you could achieve something like that when you formulate it different. For instance, I am sure that there will be some reasonable conditions such that $$E ((\hat\theta_{n+1}-\theta)^2)<E((\hat\theta_n-\theta)^2)$$Or when you start from some particular $\hat\theta_{n} $ there will be some non zero finite $k $ such that $$ E ((\hat\theta_{n+k}-\theta)^2)<(\hat\theta_n-\theta)^2$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add an extra point to the data then the estimate *may* get worse, or at least is not neccesarily becoming better.

There will always be a non-empty set of possible results for $x_{n+1}$ that will lead to a worse estimator, or at least not better.

- An example where an extra point can't make the MLE worse (but there are still points that won't make it better) is the uniform distribution 
  $\mathcal{U}(0,\theta)$ where an extra sample point can't make the MLE worse (since the MLE is the sample maximum which won't decrease upon adding an extra point). However, as Xi'an showed in his comment, the the least variance unbiased estimator for this case can get worse when you add an extra point to the sample.
- An example where the MLE can get worse is the sample mean which is the MLE in the case of estimating the mean for a normal distributed population. The sample mean can get further away from the population mean, get worse, when you increase the sample size.